# How to diagonally populate a matrix using numpy diagonal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, diagonal

Suppose I have:

`arr1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15], [16,17,18,19,20], [21,22,23,24,25]])`

And the empty matrix:

```
matrix = np.zeros((10, 10))
matrix[:] = np.NaN
```

I want to populate `matrix` with each element within `arr1`, but diagonally. This is the expected output:

```
array([[ nan, nan, nan,  nan,  nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [ 1,   nan, nan,  nan,  nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [ 6,   2,   nan,  nan,  nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [ 11,  7,   3,    nan,  nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [ 16,  12,  8,    4,    nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [ 21,  17,  13,   9,    5,   nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [ nan, 22,  18,   14,   10,  nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [ nan, nan, 23,   19,   15,  nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [ nan, nan, nan,  24,   20,  nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [ nan, nan,  nan, nan,  25,  nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```

This is what I have tried so far without succeeding:

```
arr1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15], [16,17,18,19,20], [21,22,23,24,25]])
matrix = np.zeros((10, 10))
matrix[:] = np.NaN

for i, array in enumerate(arr1):                                 
    for row_matrix in matrix:
        row_matrix = np.diag(array, -i-1)
        break
```

This is the output I have from the above code:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 21, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 22,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 23,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 24,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 25,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
for i, col in enumerate(arr1.T, 1):
    matrix[i : i + len(col), i - 1] = col

print(matrix)
```

Prints:

```
[[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [ 1. nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [ 6.  2. nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [11.  7.  3. nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [16. 12.  8.  4. nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [21. 17. 13.  9.  5. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan 22. 18. 14. 10. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan 23. 19. 15. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan 24. 20. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan 25. nan nan nan nan nan]]
```

Comment: I must confess that I was expecting this one to be slower. Because there is still one for loop (better than 2, sure). And my timings show how when n grows, OP's method explode in timing (only 2 times slower for 5x5, but 150 times slower for 5000x5000), but this method doesn't. But in fact, it is quite normal. Because it iterates only rows. And after a while, the time spent in iterating rows grows only as O(n), while time spend inside numpy's operation grows as O(n²). So, the more n grow, the less it matters.

Answer (score 1):

Without any iteration

```py
n=len(arr1)
arr2=np.full((2*n, 2*n+1), np.nan)
arr2[:n,1:n+1]=arr1.T
arr2.resize((2*n,2*n))
matrix=arr2.T
```

Just taking advantage of the fact that there a n values, and n+1 nan in between, when you read "left to right, row by row" the transposed wanted result. So, well, we do that simply in a 10x11 matrix, in which, when copied, values of arr1 have the exact same property (5 values, then 6 nan, per rows). So, after resize to 10x10, those 5 values then 6 nans imply a shift).

So, everything is about copying the data in a 1 column too big matrix, then resize it. Plus some transpose play.

### Timings

For your 5x5 example

| Method | Timing |
| --- | --- |
| Yours | 35.3 μs |
| Andrej's | 15.7 μs |
| This one | 9.1 μs |

On 5000x5000 example

| Method | Timing |
| --- | --- |
| Yours | 70.24 sec |
| Andrej's | 0.54 sec |
| This one | 0.31 sec |

Comment: Thank you @chrslg. Appreciate the benchmark in your solution.